# Native Web App Controls for pinned tabs

Tags: html, web-applications

I'm currently looking into building a web app that will have its own custom toolbars and menus. The current plan is to either run it as full screen or use pinned tabs.

If you take a look at the following video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmgtW2Iw-kE#t=213

You see that the presenter talks about how HTML5 has native controls and is one of the reasons why browser menus are hidden within pinned tabs.

The question is... How and where are these 'native' controls mentioned in the HTML spec? I was planning on just using good old fashioned HTML to build my custom UI but if there is an actual spec for doing it... I'd be interested to take a look at it first.

Anyone have any knowledge of this?

Update: I have also found this video which talks about some of it here I think: http://paulrouget.com/e/nativecontrols/